# Update a table using data of other table

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Sql Server 2005

I want to update a table using values from other table 
I have written a query but it is giving error

**"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Quantity', table 'Stationarymgmt.dbo.Item_Master'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails."**

temp table has following columns
Item_Code,
Quantity,
Cost ,
Name ,
Decription,

Item_Master table has follwing Columns
Item_Code,
Name,
Decription,
Cost ,
Quantity,

The query is

```
    UPDATE Item_Master,temp
 SET Item_Master.Quantity = Item_Master.Quantity - temp.Quantity where Item_Master.Item_Code = temp.Item_Code
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rewrite it using SQL Server's `update ... from`:

```
UPDATE  im
SET     Quantity = im.Quantity - temp.Quantity
FROM    Item_Master im
JOIN    temp
ON      im.Item_Code = temp.Item_Code
WHERE   temp.Quantity is not null
```

The `where` condition should filter out rows from `temp` which lack a quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Value - NULL = NULL the same way as 'String' + NULL = NULL

So either

```
UPDATE Item_Master,temp
SET Item_Master.Quantity = Item_Master.Quantity - ISNULL(temp.Quantity, 0) 
WHERE Item_Master.Item_Code = temp.Item_Code
```

OR

```
UPDATE Item_Master,temp
SET Item_Master.Quantity = Item_Master.Quantity - temp.Quantity 
WHERE Item_Master.Item_Code = temp.Item_Code
AND temp.Quanity IS NOT NULL
```